# Get IQueryable result view value in arraylist

Tags: linq, iqueryable

My code:

```
IQueryable grpdRows;
grpdRows = dtInput
    .Select("", "partno")
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy("new (iif(it[\"partno\"] == null, \"\", it[\"partno\"]) as GrpKey1)","it")
    .Select("new (it.Key.GrpKey1 as GrpKey1, it.Count() as TotalCount")");
```

I need to get "`grpdRows`" resuls view in an `arrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet may help you:

```
IList<string> list = new List<string>
{
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3",
    "Value4"
};

IQueryable query = list.AsQueryable();
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(query.Cast<string>().ToList());
```

You provided insufficient code so I did my example with `string` instead.